# Reactjs, how to get dimensions of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so basically what I want to reach is to get dimensions of the div element inside return method of component. I get reference to this by ref and I want to get its width and height with `getBoundingClientRect()` but there is error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined`. I also tried `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`.

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Style from 'style-it'; 
var Ink = require('react-ink');
import FontIcon from '../FontIcon/FontIcon';

var IconButton = React.createClass({ 

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          iconStyle: this.props.iconStyle,
         style: this.props.style,
          cursorPos: {},
      };
  },

  extend(obj, src) {
      Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) { obj[key] = src[key]; });
      return obj;
  },

    Tooltip() {
     var box = this.refs.button.getBoundingClientRect(),
           Height = box.clientHeight,
         tooltipStyle = {
      };

     return <div className="tooltip" style={tooltipStyle}>{this.props.tooltip}</div>;
  },

   showTooltip(){
  },

 removeTooltip(){
 },

  render() {

    var _props = this.props,
      Tooltip = this.Tooltip,
      opts,
      disabled = false,
      rippleOpacity,
     outterStyleMy = {
         border: "none",
      outline: "none",
      padding: "8px 10px",
         backgroundColor: "red",
         borderRadius: 100 + "%",
         cursor: "pointer",
     },
     iconStyleMy = {
      fontSize: 12 + "px",
      textDecoration: "none",
      textAlign: "center",
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
     },
      rippleStyle = {
        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
      };

    if (_props.disabled || _props.disableTouchRipple) {
      rippleStyle.opacity = 0;
    };

    if (_props.disabled) {
       disabled = true;
    };

    if (this.state.labelStyle) {
     iconStyleMy = this.state.iconStyle;
    };

   if (this.state.style) {
      outterStyleMy = this.state.style;
    };

    if (_props.href) {
      opts.href = _props.href;
    };

 var buttonStyle = this.extend(outterStyleMy, iconStyleMy);

     return(
        <Style>
        {`
          .IconButton{
            position: relative;
          }
          .IconButton:disabled{
            color: ${_props.disabledColor};
          }
          .btnhref{
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        `}
         <a {...opts} className="btnhref" >
         <Tooltip />
          <button ref="button" className={"IconButton" + _props.className} disabled={disabled} style={buttonStyle}
          onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip} onMouseLeave={this.removeTooltip} >
            <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
            <FontIcon className={_props.iconClassName}/>
          </button>
        </a>
        </Style>
  );

  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <IconButton href="" className="" iconStyle="" style="" iconClassName="face" disabled="" disableTouchRipple="" tooltip="aaaaa" />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

So... I don't know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a reference to a DOM node before it was rendered.

Do your `this.refs.button.getBoundingClientRect()` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to be sure it was rendered and you can get a reference to it.